# Android Out of Memory error on drawable folder

Tags: android, out-of-memory, runtime-error

In my android app, have all the images in the drawable folder. On most phones, we had no issue. But some phones have out of memory error. When the images copying for example to the drawable-xhdpi folder the issue is gone. What is the reason this problem, how can i fix it?

Comment: Images size is too big.

Comment: It depends on device's resolution. You cannot apply drawable-xhdpi to devices with low resolution. That is why there are other folders

Comment: try using picasso library

Comment: The images size not big

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`drawable` is equivalent of `drawable-mdpi`

If you put your images in that folder they will get up-sampled for higher resolutions devices and that up-sampling can trigger OOM if images are large.

If you put same sized images in `drawable-xhdpi` you will have upsampled images only on larger xxhdpi devices, and downsampled on others.

If you want to avoid automatic up/down sampling of images put them in `drawable-nodpi` folder.

Comment: Thanks the answer. I tried the drawable-nodpi folder and worked. And After couple time later the bigger screen size phone not showed the images disappeared. And copied the image to the drawable-xhdpi folder then worked again normally. Why is this happening?

Comment: I never had issues with Android not finding resource in `drawable-nodpi` folder. Android will always use images from most appropriate folder, but if it cannot find it in any dpi specific folders it will use `nodpi`. To lear more about how it chooses resources see [Providing Resources](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/providing-resources.html#BestMatch)

Answer (score 0):

Different devices might have different size limits. Try using: `drawable-xxhdpi`

Helpful cheat sheet: https://i.stack.imgur.com/kV4Oh.png

Answer (score 0):

For managing `Out Of Memory Error` one thing you may need to do is reduce the image size by compressing it and keep it in drawable folders.which is useful to reduce the app size and also memory consumption at runtime.

Or you may need to use the following class for reducing the image size aspect ratio.

**ImageResizer**

```
  public static Bitmap decodeSampledBitmapFromResource(Resources res, int resId,
                                                         int reqWidth, int reqHeight, boolean isLow) {

        // First decode with inJustDecodeBounds=true to check dimensions
        final BitmapFactory.Options options = new BitmapFactory.Options();
        options.inJustDecodeBounds = true;
        if (isLow) {
            options.inPreferredConfig = Bitmap.Config.RGB_565;
        }
        BitmapFactory.decodeResource(res, resId, options);

        // Calculate inSampleSize
        options.inSampleSize = calculateInSampleSize(options, reqWidth, reqHeight);

        // Decode bitmap with inSampleSize set
        options.inJustDecodeBounds = false;
        return BitmapFactory.decodeResource(res, resId, options);
    }


    /**
     * Calculate an inSampleSize for use in a {@link BitmapFactory.Options} object when decoding
     * bitmaps using the decode* methods from {@link BitmapFactory}. This implementation calculates
     * the closest inSampleSize that is a power of 2 and will result in the final decoded bitmap
     * having a width and height equal to or larger than the requested width and height.
     *
     * @param options   An options object with out* params already populated (run through a decode*
     *                  method with inJustDecodeBounds==true
     * @param reqWidth  The requested width of the resulting bitmap
     * @param reqHeight The requested height of the resulting bitmap
     * @return The value to be used for inSampleSize
     */
    public static int calculateInSampleSize(BitmapFactory.Options options,
                                            int reqWidth, int reqHeight) {
        // BEGIN_INCLUDE (calculate_sample_size)
        // Raw height and width of image
        final int height = options.outHeight;
        final int width = options.outWidth;
        int inSampleSize = 1;

        if (height > reqHeight || width > reqWidth) {

            final int halfHeight = height / 2;
            final int halfWidth = width / 2;

            // Calculate the largest inSampleSize value that is a power of 2 and keeps both
            // height and width larger than the requested height and width.
            while ((halfHeight / inSampleSize) > reqHeight
                    && (halfWidth / inSampleSize) > reqWidth) {
                inSampleSize *= 2;
            }

            // This offers some additional logic in case the image has a strange
            // aspect ratio. For example, a panorama may have a much larger
            // width than height. In these cases the total pixels might still
            // end up being too large to fit comfortably in memory, so we should
            // be more aggressive with sample down the image (=larger inSampleSize).

            long totalPixels = width * height / inSampleSize;

            // Anything more than 2x the requested pixels we'll sample down further
            final long totalReqPixelsCap = reqWidth * reqHeight * 2;

            while (totalPixels > totalReqPixelsCap) {
                inSampleSize *= 2;
                totalPixels /= 2;
            }
        }
        return inSampleSize;
        // END_INCLUDE (calculate_sample_size)
    }
```

**Usage**

```
   private Bitmap mBackground;
   private Drawable mBackgroundDrawable;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            LinearLayout linearLayout = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.parent);
            final Resources res = getResources();
            int[] dimensions = Util.getDisplayDimensions(this);
            mBackground = ImageResizer.decodeSampledBitmapFromResource(res, R.drawable.bg, 100, 100, false);
            mBackgroundDrawable = new BitmapDrawable(res, mBackground);
            linearLayout.setBackground(mBackgroundDrawable);
         }

    @Override
    protected void onDestroy() {
        recycle();
        super.onDestroy();
    }

    private void recycle() {
        if (mBackground != null) {
            mBackground.recycle();
            mBackground = null;
            if (mBackgroundDrawable != null)
                mBackgroundDrawable = null;

        }
    }
```

**Note :** If your applying `true` as third argument which help you to reduce the image size effectively using [`Bitmap.Config.RGB_565`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/Bitmap.Config.html).

```
         if (isLow) {
             options.inPreferredConfig = Bitmap.Config.RGB_565;
           }
```

> Finally, research about OOM.